# Titanium Alloy change url of webview, undefined

Tags: android, ios, webview, titanium, titanium-alloy

## **TL;DR** I need to change the URL of a WebView I previously created in **alloy.js** inside a new controller but the URL is not changing no matter what I do. How do I do this?

====================================

I've been having problems left and right with Titanium's webview... Require serious assistance ASAP.

I'm using Alloy. What I'm trying to do is to change the URL of a webview that I've previously created in **alloy.js**.

My **alloy.js** file first creates a webview:

```
Alloy.Globals.webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView();
Alloy.Globals.setUserAgent(); //function that just sets the user agent
Alloy.Globals.webview.url = "http://www.google.ca";
```

Then on **index.js**, I have a button where when clicked, it creates and opens a new controller (the controller that contains the webview:

```
var win = $.index;
...
button.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    var theTest = Alloy.createController('web').getView();
    theTest.open();
    win.close();
});
```

On **web.js**, I add the WebView (from alloy.js) to a view:

```
$.view_webview.add(Alloy.Globals.webview);
```

Still on **web.js**, I have another view (acts as a button) where when I click on it, it tries to change the url of this the webview I made in **alloy.js**:

```
view_getpoints.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    $.Alloy.Globals.webview.url = "http://www.youtube.com";
    $.Alloy.Globals.webview.reload();
});
```

This did not work, the url did not change. It was still on google.
I also tried setUrl("http://youtube.com"); instead of just url, nothing.

I then figured it might be because I'm trying to change just the variable, where when I really should be directly changing the element object I added to my **$.view_webview** view. So I tried that:

```
view_getpoints.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    $.view_webview.getChildren(0).url = "http://www.youtube.com";
}
```

Aw man, "url" is undefined? Maybe I'm getting the child wrong. Let's output **$.view_webview.getChildren(0)** and see what we get:

```
view_getpoints.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Ti.API.info("child: " + $.view_webview.getChildren(0));
}
```

I was expecting this to output "child: undefined" but no...it isn't undefined..It outputs: "child: [object WebView]".

Whoa whoa whoa, hold on back up. It knows it's a WebView object? But...shouldn't I be able to access the url and setUrl() fields from this object then as stated by the docs?
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-property-url

Why can't I change it directly?
I'm out of options.

**TL;DR** I need to change the URL of a WebView I previously created in **alloy.js** inside a new controller. How do I do this?

Comment: Small test, try removing `Alloy.Globals.webview.url = "http://www.google.ca";` from **alloy.js** and add it to **web.js**

Comment: And better to use `setUrl()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.